# Is the Firebase auth client thread safe?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go in my Go server application.

After looking at the documentation, I'm creating the auth.Client every time I'm checking the ID token. E. g.:

```
client, err := firebaseApp.Auth(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
token, err := client.VerifyIDToken(ctx, idToken)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```

I'm already sharing the `firebaseApp` (a `firebase.App`) between goroutines.

My question: Is it safe to also share the `auth.Client` between goroutines or do I need to create one every time I verify the ID token? That would mean I will create one for almost every authenticated request. That seems costly to me.
I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is goroutine safe.

`auth.Client` is intended to be shared among goroutines and reused. Specifically, the `VerifyIDToken()` function will cache the public keys between invocations. You should reuse the client instance to benefit from this. `auth.Client` performs its own locking/synchronization internally, when required ([e.g.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/tree/master/auth#L69)).

Comment: Is that the case for all the Firebase Go clients? eg. `app.Firestore(ctx)`?

Comment: Yes, you should feel free to reuse/share clients unless otherwise specified.

Comment: I have noticed that transactions are not thread safe. Bummer. ==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0004bde90 by goroutine 99:
  cloud.google.com/go/firestore.(*Transaction).addWrites()
      /home/jens/go/pkg/mod/cloud.google.com/go@v0.28.0/firestore/transaction.go:270 +0x124

Comment: Not sure if that's intentional or not. I'd try reporting at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go